# What makes something a producer for a DirectProcessor?

Tags: java, spring-reactor

From [DirectProcessor](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/DirectProcessor.html), [spring-reactor 3.x](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/) documentation:

> Dispatches onNext, onError and onComplete signals to zero-to-many
>   Subscribers. Please note, that along with multiple consumers, current
>   implementation of DirectProcessor supports multiple producers.
>   However, all producers must produce messages on the same Thread,
>   otherwise Reactive Streams Spec contract is violated.

What a *producer* is in the above declaration?

1. a `Publisher` receiving a [DirectProcessor](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/DirectProcessor.html) as parameter for [Publisher.subscribe](https://www.reactive-streams.org/reactive-streams-1.0.3-javadoc/org/reactivestreams/Publisher.html?is-external=true#subscribe(org.reactivestreams.Subscriber)) metod
2. something calling `DirectProcessor.onNext(T t)`
3. something calling `FluxSink<T>.next(T t)` where [FluxSink](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/FluxSink.html) is the result of `DirectProcessor.sink()`

Comment: you answered your own question it seems

Comment: You mean that all and only those options specified by me are the answer?